# Angular 4 Routing with nested components

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to have a routing like this:
root
root/childA
root/childB
root/childC

The root is a dashboard component that has links to the children but after clicking them, the dashboard does not remain, it only gets replaced by the children. It would be a mobile friendly UI that has back buttons and breadcrumbs.
Which is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.  Define your path something like:

```
{ path: 'root', children: (<Routes> [
  { path: '', component: RootComponent, },
  { path: 'childA', component: ChildAComponent, },
  { path: 'childB', component: ChildBComponent, },
  { path: 'childC', component: ChildCComponent, },
])}
```

Check the angular tutorials for info on breadcrumb.  For mobile friendly look at responsive development (i.e. through bootstrap or otherwise).

Good luck.